# Understanding malloc and flexible array members

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, flexible-array-member

I am curious of how `malloc()` actually allocates memory. I am reading C programming by K.N.King for reference. In particular, chapter 17. Initially in the chapter `void *malloc(size_t size)` is described as function which allocates a block of memory of `size` bytes and returns a `void *` pointer to this memory block. Two main applications being dynamically allocating strings and arrays. When `malloc()` is called the returned pointer will be cast to the appropriate type, for example in,

```
int *n;
n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
```

the `malloc()` return will be cast to `(int *)`. It was my understanding that since this cast occurs the memory block allocated by the call of `malloc()` contains uninitialised integers. However, after more reading in the chapter I think I am wrong but I can't figure out exactly what is going on.

The conflict in understanding occurred when reading the last section of the chapter on flexible array members. The idea of defining a structure with the last member being "incomplete", i.e.,

```
struct vstring {
    int len;
    char chars[];
};
```

The author then goes on to say, and I quote:

> A structure that contains a flexible array member is an ***incomplete type***. An incomplete type is missing part of the information needed to determine how much memory it requires. ... In particular, an incomplete type can't be a member of another structure or an element of an array. However, and array may contains pointers to structure that have a flexible array member.

So clearly my earlier understand must be flawed otherwise a call such as,

```
struct vstring *str = malloc(sizeof(struct vstring) + n);
```

would allocate an array containing an incomplete type.

Is the block of memory allocated by `malloc()` an array of a particular type after being cast? If not, then how can the following work,

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
new_node->value = 10;
```

if the memory allocated by the `malloc()` call is not declared as elements of `struct node`? Even the integer array example I put at the beginning of the post, I would be able to access the elements of the the allocated memory by subscripting `n` immediately.

Comment: **How `malloc`  is implemented is operating system specific**. On Linux,  it often uses [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and you could download then study the source code of [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/) or of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). Learn also to use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Read also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: The book is wrong when it says that a structure type with a flexible array member is an incomplete type.  The type of the flexible array member itself is incomplete, but the type of the structure containing it is not.  Structure types containing FAMs have some special rules and restrictions, but they can be used in several ways that incomplete types cannot.  For example, they are acceptable operands for the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have commented further on Eric's post. According to the text, the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate to `chars[]` prior to explicitly allocating memory to the structure. In that sense, is the structure not an incomplete type? In particular, this would imply that the compiler doesn't know the number of bytes required for the structure and `sizeof(struct vstring)` would fail?

Comment: @Zeta-Squared: The standard’s wording for flexible array members is a kludge. C 2018 6.2.5 1 indicates a type is *incomplete* at a point in a translation unit if the information about the type lacks sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type. By that criterion, a structure with a flexible array member is incomplete. But 6.7.2.1 18 says the size of the structure is “as if” the flexible array member were omitted except there may be more trailing padding. So, for this purpose, the structure does have a known size. For most purposes of the standard, the type is complete.

Comment: Haha, ok perhaps this is a rabbit hole that is best left untouched. Thank you for helping a learning programmer. I will accept your answer. Good day.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared, "incomplete type" is a defined term in the C language specification, and a structure type with a FAM doers not meet that definition.  For structure types, it is: " A structure or union type of unknown content (as described in 6.7.2.3) is an incomplete type. It is completed, for all declarations of that type, by declaring the same structure or union tag with its defining content later in the same scope" (C17 6.2.5/22).  Whether one of the members is a FAM is irrelevant to that definition.

Comment: Other things you can do with a structure type that has a FAM, but not with an incomplete type include defining (as opposed to merely declaring) a static or automatic object having the type in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the `malloc()` return will be cast to `(int *)`.

There is no cast in `n = malloc(sizeof(*n));`. A cast is an explicit operator in source code, the way a plus sign is an operator for addition or an asterisk is an operator for multiplication. A cast is a type name in parentheses. In `n = malloc(sizeof(*n));`, the value returned by `malloc` is automatically converted to the type of `n`, which is `int *`. This is a conversion, not a cast.

> Is the block of memory allocated by `malloc()` an array of a particular type after being cast?

The memory allocated by `malloc` has no declared type. For formal semantic and technical reasons in the C standard, it takes on an effective type once you store data into it. This is largely irrelevant to ordinary use as long as you are not trying to do anything “funny” with the memory, such as using it as different types at different types.

> If not, then how can the following work…

Once you have used `malloc` to allocate sufficient memory for an object, you may store a value for that object into the allocated memory.

> … if the memory allocated by the `malloc()` call is not declared as elements of `struct node`?

The effective type of the memory is determined by the type of the *lvalue* expression used to store to the memory. An *lvalue* is an expression that potentially designates an object. For a declared object, as with `int x;`, the name of the object, `x`, is an lvalue expression for it. When we have a pointer, as with `int *p;`, then `*p` is an lvalue expression for the object that `p` points to (assuming it is a valid pointer to memory for such an object, not a null pointer or an invalid pointer).

Have assigned `new_node` to point to memory allocated with `malloc`, then `*new_node` is an lvalue expression for the appropriate type, `struct node`, and `new_node->value` is an lvalue expression for the `int` member of `struct node`. Using these lvalue expressions informs the compiler about how to treat the memory at those locations.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand. So the memory allocated by `malloc` is somewhat of a "blank canvas" in that it's converted to a type of the lvalue. Which makes sense to me in the `struct node` case, since we can consider the memory block allocated to act somewhat like an array, that is, iterating the pointer `new_node` will iterate through the elements of the block. However, I still don't see why this doesn't hold for FAMs. In that case, the memory block does not get iterated through elements of FAMs but rather the the `chars[]` member of a single FAM structure. Why is it different for FAMs?

Comment: I think I answered my comment by re-reading the section: "The length of the `chars` array isn't determined until memory is allocated for a `vstring` structure, normally using a call of `malloc`"

So the compiler does not know how much memory `struct vstring` requires until we assign it because of the `chars[]` member. In which case a call of:

`struct vstring *str = malloc(sizeof(struct vstring) + n);`

will allocated the size of bytes passed to `malloc`, of which 4 bytes will be allocated to the `int` member of `vstring` and the remainder to `chars[]`.

Comment: With this in mind, would that not mean that @John Bollinger's comment on the original post is incorrect, since the compiler doesn't know the number of bytes requires for `struct vstring` prior to allocating it memory?

Comment: @Zeta-Squared, you seem to have the idea.  I would suggest, however, that instead of thinking in terms of how much space a FAM *requires*, think in terms of how much space it *has*, which can vary from instance to instance of the host struct, and may be zero.  In the event of a reallocation, the space a given FAM has might even change during the lifetime of the host struct.